# Multivariate normal density in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability

Is there any python package that allows the efficient computation of the PDF (probability density function) of a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)?

It doesn't seem to be included in Numpy/Scipy, and surprisingly a Google search didn't turn up any useful thing.

Comment: @pyCthon Yes, I know my covariance matrix is positive definite from the way it is constructed

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The multivariate normal is now available on `SciPy 0.14.0.dev-16fc0af`:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
var = multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0], cov=[[1,0],[0,1]])
var.pdf([1,0])
```

Comment: I tried to evaluate it on a grid the numbers kind of resemble a gaussian but the sum is bigger then 1!  Not what I expected...

Comment: Be aware that densities can be greater than one. You need to integrate the density times the infinitesimal rectangles to get one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Thinking a bit more about it: In a 1d PDF probabilities are actually only defined for a range and not a point value. Somehow the `.pdf (..)` method returns values that make sense after normalizing them again. But the SciPy docs do not talk much about it.

Answer (score 36):

I just made one for my purposes so I though I'd share. It's built using "the powers" of numpy, on the formula of the non degenerate case from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution and it aso validates the input.

Here is the code along with a sample run

```
from numpy import *
import math
# covariance matrix
sigma = matrix([[2.3, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1.5, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1.7, 0],
           [0, 0,   0, 2]
          ])
# mean vector
mu = array([2,3,8,10])

# input
x = array([2.1,3.5,8, 9.5])

def norm_pdf_multivariate(x, mu, sigma):
    size = len(x)
    if size == len(mu) and (size, size) == sigma.shape:
        det = linalg.det(sigma)
        if det == 0:
            raise NameError("The covariance matrix can't be singular")

        norm_const = 1.0/ ( math.pow((2*pi),float(size)/2) * math.pow(det,1.0/2) )
        x_mu = matrix(x - mu)
        inv = sigma.I        
        result = math.pow(math.e, -0.5 * (x_mu * inv * x_mu.T))
        return norm_const * result
    else:
        raise NameError("The dimensions of the input don't match")

print norm_pdf_multivariate(x, mu, sigma)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `math.pow(x, 1.0/2)` rather than `math.sqrt(x)`, and similarly, why use `math.pow(math.e, x)` over `math.exp(x)`?

Answer (score 18):

If still needed, my implementation would be

```
import numpy as np

def pdf_multivariate_gauss(x, mu, cov):
    '''
    Caculate the multivariate normal density (pdf)

    Keyword arguments:
        x = numpy array of a "d x 1" sample vector
        mu = numpy array of a "d x 1" mean vector
        cov = "numpy array of a d x d" covariance matrix
    '''
    assert(mu.shape[0] > mu.shape[1]), 'mu must be a row vector'
    assert(x.shape[0] > x.shape[1]), 'x must be a row vector'
    assert(cov.shape[0] == cov.shape[1]), 'covariance matrix must be square'
    assert(mu.shape[0] == cov.shape[0]), 'cov_mat and mu_vec must have the same dimensions'
    assert(mu.shape[0] == x.shape[0]), 'mu and x must have the same dimensions'
    part1 = 1 / ( ((2* np.pi)**(len(mu)/2)) * (np.linalg.det(cov)**(1/2)) )
    part2 = (-1/2) * ((x-mu).T.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov))).dot((x-mu))
    return float(part1 * np.exp(part2))

def test_gauss_pdf():
    x = np.array([[0],[0]])
    mu  = np.array([[0],[0]])
    cov = np.eye(2) 

    print(pdf_multivariate_gauss(x, mu, cov))

    # prints 0.15915494309189535

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_gauss_pdf()
```

In case I make future changes, the code is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/useful_scripts/multivariate_gaussian_pdf.py)

Answer (score 8):

In the common case of a diagonal covariance matrix, the multivariate PDF can be obtained by simply multiplying the univariate PDF values returned by a `scipy.stats.norm` instance.  If you need the general case, you will probably have to code this yourself (which shouldn't be hard).

Comment: Could you be more specific of how to use norm to calculate the probability? Big thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

You can easily compute using numpy. I have implemented as below for the purpose of machine learning course and would like to share, hope it helps to someone.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[13.04681517, 14.74115241],[13.40852019, 13.7632696 ],[14.19591481, 15.85318113],[14.91470077, 16.17425987]])

def est_gaus_par(X):
    mu = np.mean(X,axis=0)
    sig = np.std(X,axis=0)
    return mu,sig

mu,sigma = est_gaus_par(X)

def est_mult_gaus(X,mu,sigma):
    m = len(mu)
    sigma2 = np.diag(sigma)
    X = X-mu.T
    p = 1/((2*np.pi)**(m/2)*np.linalg.det(sigma2)**(0.5))*np.exp(-0.5*np.sum(X.dot(np.linalg.pinv(sigma2))*X,axis=1))

    return p

p = est_mult_gaus(X, mu, sigma)
```

Comment: This was helpful for me when trying to convert the identical function to cupy. I did need to use cp.diag(cp.diag(sigma)) when using a covariance matrix. Thx,

Answer (score 3):

I know of several python packages that use it internally, with different generality and for different uses, but I don't know if any of them are intended for users.

statsmodels, for example, has the following hidden function and class, but it's not used by statsmodels:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/miscmodels/try_mlecov.py#L36

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/distributions/mv_normal.py#L777

Essentially, if you need fast evaluation, rewrite it for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code which calculates the logpdf value, which is preferable for larger dimensions. It also works for scipy.sparse matrices.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spln

def lognormpdf(x,mu,S):
    """ Calculate gaussian probability density of x, when x ~ N(mu,sigma) """
    nx = len(S)
    norm_coeff = nx*math.log(2*math.pi)+np.linalg.slogdet(S)[1]

    err = x-mu
    if (sp.issparse(S)):
        numerator = spln.spsolve(S, err).T.dot(err)
    else:
        numerator = np.linalg.solve(S, err).T.dot(err)

    return -0.5*(norm_coeff+numerator)
```

Code is from [pyParticleEst](http://www.control.lth.se/Staff/JerkerNordh/pyparticleest.html), if you want the pdf value instead of the logpdf just take math.exp() on the returned value

Answer (score 2):

The density can be computed in a pretty straightforward way using numpy functions and the formula on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution. You may also want to use the likelihood function (log probability), which is less likely to underflow for large dimensions and is a little more straightforward to compute. Both just involve being able to compute the determinant and inverse of a matrix.

The CDF, on the other hand, is an entirely different animal...

Answer (score 1):

Here I elaborate a bit more on how exactly to use the [multivariate_normal()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) from the scipy package:

```
# Import packages
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# Prepare your data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# Get the multivariate normal distribution
mu_x = np.mean(x)
sigma_x = np.std(x)
mu_y = np.mean(y)
sigma_y = np.std(y)
rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[sigma_x, 0], [0, sigma_y]])

# Get the probability density
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y
pd = rv.pdf(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped me to solve,when given a vector what is the likelihood that vector is in a multivariate normal distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
```

## data with all vectors

```
d= np.array([[1,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5,4],[2,2,1]])
```

## mean of the data in vector form, which will have same length as input vector(here its 3)

```
mean = sum(d,axis=0)/len(d)

OR
mean=np.average(d , axis=0)
mean.shape
```

## finding covarianve of vectors which will have shape of [input vector shape X input vector shape] here it is 3x3

```
cov = 0
for e in d:
  cov += np.dot((e-mean).reshape(len(e), 1), (e-mean).reshape(1, len(e)))
cov /= len(d)
cov.shape
```

## preparing a multivariate Gaussian distribution from mean and co variance

```
dist = multivariate_normal(mean,cov)
```

## finding probability distribution function.

```
print(dist.pdf([1,2,3]))

3.050863384798471e-05
```

The above value gives the likelihood.

Comment: in `d`, are the rows or the columns the signals? If you have 4 signals with 3 elements each, then the covariance should be 4x4